# How to un-nest and group collections in mongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, document-database

I'm don't understand how to unwind and then nested collections in mongoDB. basically I have two collections that are structured like this:

questions doc:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "questions" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "body" : "What fabric is the top made of?",
            "date_written" : "2018-01-04",
            "asker_name" : "yankeelover",
            "asker_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
            "reported" : 0,
            "helpful" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "body" : "HEY THIS IS A WEIRD QUESTION!!!!?",
            "date_written" : "2019-04-28",
            "asker_name" : "jbilas",
            "asker_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
            "reported" : 1,
            "helpful" : 4
        },
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "body" : "How long does it last?",
            "date_written" : "2019-07-06",
            "asker_name" : "funnygirl",
            "asker_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
            "reported" : 0,
            "helpful" : 6
        },
```

answers doc:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "answers" : [
        {
            "_id" : 8,
            "body" : "DONT BUY IT! It's bad for the environment",
            "date_written" : "2018-01-04",
            "answerer_name" : "metslover",
            "answerer_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
            "reported" : 0,
            "helpful" : 8
        },
        {
            "_id" : 7,
            "body" : "Its the best! Seriously magic fabric",
            "date_written" : "2018-01-04",
            "answerer_name" : "metslover",
            "answerer_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
            "reported" : 0,
            "helpful" : 7
        },
        {
            "_id" : 5,
            "body" : "Something pretty soft but I can't be sure",
            "date_written" : "2018-01-04",
            "answerer_name" : "metslover",
            "answerer_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
            "reported" : 0,
            "helpful" : 5,
            "photos" : [
                {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "url" : "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530519729491-aea5b51d1ee1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1651&q=80"
                },
```

The _id field in the answers doc matches the _id field of the questions for which they are the answers too.

the end goal is to have data that looks something like this:

```
{
    "_id": "17762",
    "questions": [
        {
            "question_id": 152829,
            "question_body": "Why Does it look like this?",
            "question_date": "2021-03-06T00:00:00.000Z",
            "asker_name": "garethTheGreato",
            "question_helpfulness": 60,
            "reported": false,
            "answers": {
                "1443770": {
                    "id": 1443770,
                    "body": "This question was really helpful! Thank you.",
                    "date": "2021-03-09T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "answerer_name": "SatisfiedCustomer",
                    "helpfulness": 3,
                    "photos": []
                },
                "1443807": {
                    "id": 1443807,
                    "body": "mimk",
                    "date": "2021-03-09T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "answerer_name": "jij",
                    "helpfulness": 3,
                    "photos": [
                        "blob:http://localhost:3000/8f6375b3-0795-4210-bef7-f112feed8244"
                    ]
                },
                "1443834": {
                    "id": 1443834,
                    "body": "10/10 would recomend.",
                    "date": "2021-03-09T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "answerer_name": "Krista",
                    "helpfulness": 2,
                    "photos": []
                },
                "1443845": {
                    "id": 1443845,
                    "body": "Thank you so much for playing my game!",
                    "date": "2021-03-10T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "answerer_name": "itsameemario",
                    "helpfulness": 1,
                    "photos": []
                },
                "1443880": {
                    "id": 1443880,
                    "body": "Tree",
                    "date": "2021-03-10T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "answerer_name": "Tree",
                    "helpfulness": 0,
                    "photos": [
                        "blob:http://localhost:3000/123051b6-4dfb-410a-a96f-d4a5128e3056"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "question_id": 152702,
            "question_body": "Please write your question here",
            "question_date": "2021-03-05T00:00:00.000Z",
            "asker_name": "Your nickname",
            "question_helpfulness": 32,
            "reported": false,
            "answers": {}
        },
```

The problem I'm having is that when I run the lookup I get an answers array that correlates to the questions collection but am not sure how to get each set of answers to their specific question given that the answers come back deeply nested.

Here is what I have so far: (the ignore the slice and sorts for now these are parameters I will need for later as another part of the project)

```
  db.prodquests.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: 5 } },
    { $unwind: '$questions' },
    { $match: { 'questions.reported': { $lt: 1 } } },
    { $sort: { 'questions.helpful': -1 } },
    { $group: { _id: '$_id', questions: { $push: '$questions' } } },
    { $project: { _id: 1, questions: { $slice: ['$questions', 0, 1] } } },
    { $unwind: '$questions' },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'groupansphotos',
        localField: 'questions._id',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'answers',
      },
    },
  ])
```

The return from this statement is as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "questions" : {
        "_id" : 37,
        "body" : "Why is this product cheaper here than other sites?",
        "date_written" : "2018-10-18",
        "asker_name" : "willsmith",
        "asker_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
        "reported" : 0,
        "helpful" : 4
    },
    "answers" : [
        {
            "_id" : 37,
            "answers" : [
                {
                    "_id" : 68,
                    "body" : "We are selling it here without any markup from the middleman!",
                    "date_written" : "2018-08-18",
                    "answerer_name" : "Seller",
                    "answerer_email" : "null",
                    "reported" : 0,
                    "helpful" : 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Essentially I want to group just that answers array under it's corresponding questions for which the _id field matches.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** based on comments:

Updated query:

```js
db.questions.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: 5 } },
    { $unwind: '$questions' },
    { $match: { 'questions.reported': { $lt: 1 } } },
    { $sort: { 'questions.helpful': -1 } },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "answers",
            let: { question_id: "$questions._id" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$question_id"] }
                    }
                },
                { $unwind: "$answers" },
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 0,
                        k: { $toString: "$answers._id" },
                        v: "$$ROOT.answers"
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "answers"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            questions: {
                $push: {
                    question_id: "$questions._id",
                    question_body: "$questions.body",
                    question_date: "$questions.date_written",
                    asker_name: "$questions.asker_name",
                    question_helpfulness: "$questions.helpful",
                    reported: "$questions.reported",
                    answers: { $arrayToObject: "$answers" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Old query:

**Note**: Plz fix the collection name and/or field names. Try this query:

```js
db.questions.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: 5 } },
    { $unwind: '$questions' },
    { $match: { 'questions.reported': { $lt: 1 } } },
    { $sort: { 'questions.helpful': -1 } },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "answers",
            let: { question_id: "$questions._id" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$question_id"] }
                    }
                },
                { $unwind: "$answers" },
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 0,
                        k: { $toString: "$answers._id" },
                        v: "$$ROOT.answers"
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "answers"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $gt: [{ $size: "$answers" }, 0]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            questions: {
                $push: {
                    question_id: "$questions._id",
                    question_body: "$questions.body",
                    question_date: "$questions.date_written",
                    asker_name: "$questions.asker_name",
                    question_helpfulness: "$questions.helpful",
                    reported: "$questions.reported",
                    answers: { $arrayToObject: "$answers" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "questions" : [
        {
            "question_id" : 2,
            "question_body" : "HEY THIS IS A WEIRD QUESTION!!!!?",
            "question_date" : "2019-04-28",
            "asker_name" : "jbilas",
            "question_helpfulness" : 4,
            "reported" : 0,
            "answers" : {
                "14" : {
                    "_id" : 14,
                    "body" : "DONT BUY IT! It's bad for the environment",
                    "date_written" : "2018-01-04",
                    "answerer_name" : "metslover",
                    "answerer_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
                    "reported" : 0,
                    "helpful" : 8
                },
                "15" : {
                    "_id" : 15,
                    "body" : "Its the best! Seriously magic fabric",
                    "date_written" : "2018-01-04",
                    "answerer_name" : "metslover",
                    "answerer_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
                    "reported" : 0,
                    "helpful" : 7
                },
                "16" : {
                    "_id" : 16,
                    "body" : "Something pretty soft but I can't be sure",
                    "date_written" : "2018-01-04",
                    "answerer_name" : "metslover",
                    "answerer_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
                    "reported" : 0,
                    "helpful" : 5
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "question_id" : 1,
            "question_body" : "What fabric is the top made of?",
            "question_date" : "2018-01-04",
            "asker_name" : "yankeelover",
            "question_helpfulness" : 2,
            "reported" : 0,
            "answers" : {
                "11" : {
                    "_id" : 11,
                    "body" : "DONT BUY IT! It's bad for the environment",
                    "date_written" : "2018-01-04",
                    "answerer_name" : "metslover",
                    "answerer_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
                    "reported" : 0,
                    "helpful" : 8
                },
                "12" : {
                    "_id" : 12,
                    "body" : "Its the best! Seriously magic fabric",
                    "date_written" : "2018-01-04",
                    "answerer_name" : "metslover",
                    "answerer_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
                    "reported" : 0,
                    "helpful" : 7
                },
                "13" : {
                    "_id" : 13,
                    "body" : "Something pretty soft but I can't be sure",
                    "date_written" : "2018-01-04",
                    "answerer_name" : "metslover",
                    "answerer_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
                    "reported" : 0,
                    "helpful" : 5
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Test data:

`questions` collection

```js
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "questions" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "body" : "What fabric is the top made of?",
            "date_written" : "2018-01-04",
            "asker_name" : "yankeelover",
            "asker_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
            "reported" : 0,
            "helpful" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "body" : "HEY THIS IS A WEIRD QUESTION!!!!?",
            "date_written" : "2019-04-28",
            "asker_name" : "jbilas",
            "asker_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
            "reported" : 0,
            "helpful" : 4
        },
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "body" : "How long does it last?",
            "date_written" : "2019-07-06",
            "asker_name" : "funnygirl",
            "asker_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
            "reported" : 0,
            "helpful" : 6
        }
    ]
}
```

`answers` collection:

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "answers" : [
        {
            "_id" : 11,
            "body" : "DONT BUY IT! It's bad for the environment",
            "date_written" : "2018-01-04",
            "answerer_name" : "metslover",
            "answerer_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
            "reported" : 0,
            "helpful" : 8
        },
        {
            "_id" : 12,
            "body" : "Its the best! Seriously magic fabric",
            "date_written" : "2018-01-04",
            "answerer_name" : "metslover",
            "answerer_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
            "reported" : 0,
            "helpful" : 7
        },
        {
            "_id" : 13,
            "body" : "Something pretty soft but I can't be sure",
            "date_written" : "2018-01-04",
            "answerer_name" : "metslover",
            "answerer_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
            "reported" : 0,
            "helpful" : 5
        }
    ]
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "answers" : [
        {
            "_id" : 14,
            "body" : "DONT BUY IT! It's bad for the environment",
            "date_written" : "2018-01-04",
            "answerer_name" : "metslover",
            "answerer_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
            "reported" : 0,
            "helpful" : 8
        },
        {
            "_id" : 15,
            "body" : "Its the best! Seriously magic fabric",
            "date_written" : "2018-01-04",
            "answerer_name" : "metslover",
            "answerer_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
            "reported" : 0,
            "helpful" : 7
        },
        {
            "_id" : 16,
            "body" : "Something pretty soft but I can't be sure",
            "date_written" : "2018-01-04",
            "answerer_name" : "metslover",
            "answerer_email" : "first.last@gmail.com",
            "reported" : 0,
            "helpful" : 5
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much!

Having the pipeline in the lookup stage seems to be very powerful and I hope to master it as you have.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the match stage in the lookup from excluding the local documents that don't have a match in the answers document?

Comment: We cannot do that from inside of the `$lookup` stage. From outside we can use `$unwind` on the field resulting from the join operation to exclude documents from outer/local collection, but in your case we cant use `$unwind` since we need that array to covert it to object.

Comment: Yeah I see what you are saying. I'm thinking now that maybe the best thing to do is make sure there is always a match in the answers collection, even if the answers for a respective question ID is just an empty array

Comment: I guess my new question is:

Is there a way to add an empty answers array for each question that doest have an answers match in the 

for example if question _id: 5 doesn't have an _id match in answers: I would insert a document = { _id: 5, answers= [ ] } that I can push to later

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear.


 Right now when I perform the join with the selected questions the questions will be removed from the final results if they do not have a matching answers document.

I want to include ALL the questions being returned from the original match stage before the lookup just joined with their answers if they exist

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check if it helps. Just removed the `$match` stage before `$group`.

Comment: Wow that was a really simple fix. I can see now that was definitely looking at the problem wrong. Thanks so much for your help!!!